# Stop to bring duplicate results based in a condition

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Even though my query is behaving the way it should be, I have an issue in the records that I can't fix in the database.
So, I want to fix it in the query.

The issue is: as the image attached, for one specific customer, there are duplicate IDs due to the Sales Person being different.

I need to bring just one result for these IDs, doesn't matter the salesperson.

I've tried:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(al.agr_header_recid, '-', ap.month, '-', ap.year) AS id,
    al.Company_Name,
    ah.AGR_Name,
    al.agr_type_desc,
    al.Valid_flag,
    CAST(al.DateStart AS DATE) AS date_start,
    CAST(al.DateEND AS DATE) AS date_end,
    al.Billing_Cycle_Desc AS billing_cycle,
    al.Billing_Amount,
    al.Agreement_Status,
    o.Owner_Level_Name AS 'Sales Person',

    
    CASE
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'False' THEN 'Time'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'False' THEN 'Time & Expenses'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'True' THEN 'Time, Products, & Expenses'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'True' THEN 'Time & Products'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'False' THEN 'Expenses'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'True' THEN 'Products & Expenses'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'True' THEN 'Products'
    ELSE NULL
END AS agreement_covers_list
,CASE ah.AGR_NoEnd_Flag
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
END AS no_end_flag


,COALESCE(ap.Rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0) AS total_revenue
,CAST(ap.Agr_Date_inv AS DATE) AS date_agreement_invoiced
,COALESCE(ap.Hours, 0) + COALESCE(child.hours, 0) AS total_agreement_hours
,COALESCE(ap.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.labor_Cost, 0) AS total_labor_cost
,COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0) AS total_addition_cost
,CAST(CASE WHEN child.parent_recid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS has_child_agreement
,child.child_agreeements
,child.child_agreeement_types
,child.count AS number_of_child_agreements
,child.rev AS child_revenue
,ap.Rev AS parent_revenue
,ap.Hours AS parent_hours
,child.hours AS child_Hours
,ap.labor_Cost AS parent_labor_cost
,child.labor_Cost AS child_labor_cost
,ap.prod_cost AS parent_addition_cost
,child.prod_cost AS child_addition_cost
,COALESCE(ap.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0)
    + COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0) AS total_cost
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(ap.hours, 0) + COALESCE(child.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE (COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0))/(COALESCE(ap.hours, 0) + COALESCE(child.hours, 0))
END AS total_all_ehr
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(ap.hours, 0) + COALESCE(child.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE ((COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0)) - (COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0)))
           /(COALESCE(ap.hours, 0) + COALESCE(child.hours, 0))
END AS total_no_addition_cost_ehr
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(ap.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE (COALESCE(ap.rev, 0))/(COALESCE(ap.hours, 0))
END AS parent_all_ehr
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(ap.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE (COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) - COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0))/(COALESCE(ap.hours, 0))
END AS parent_no_addition_cost_ehr
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(child.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE (COALESCE(child.rev, 0) - COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0))/(COALESCE(child.hours, 0))
END AS child_no_addition_cost_ehr
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(child.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE (COALESCE(child.rev, 0))/(COALESCE(child.hours, 0))
END AS child_all_ehr
,(COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0))
    - (COALESCE(ap.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0))
AS total_agreement_margin
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0)) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ((COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0))
            - (COALESCE(ap.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0)
                + COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0)))
        / ((COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0)))
END AS total_agreement_margin_percentage


FROM AGR_Header AS ah

INNER JOIN v_rpt_AgreementList AS al ON ah.AGR_Header_RecID = al.AGR_Header_RecID
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                    Company_RecID,
                    territory_recid

            FROM Billing_Log

            GROUP BY Company_RecID, territory_recid) AS bl ON ah.Company_RecID = bl.Company_RecID

INNER JOIN Owner_Level AS o ON bl.territory_recid = o.Owner_Level_RecID
INNER JOIN (SELECT ar.AGR_Header_RecID
            ,ar.Month
            ,ar.Year
            ,ar.Agr_Date_inv
            ,ar.Rev
            ,ac.Hours AS hours
            ,ac.Cost AS labor_cost
            ,addi.prod_cost
            FROM
                (SELECT ah.AGR_Header_RecID
                ,ai.Month_Nbr AS month
                ,ai.Year_Nbr AS year
                ,CONVERT (VARCHAR(8), ai.Year_Nbr, 120) + '-' + RIGHT ('0' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(8), ai.Month_nbr, 120), 2)
                    + '-' + '01' AS agr_date_inv
                ,CAST(SUM(ai.Monthly_Inv_Amt - ai.Monthly_SalesTax_Amt) AS NUMERIC (18, 2)) AS rev
                FROM agr_header AS ah
                INNER JOIN agr_invoice_amt AS ai ON ah.AGR_Header_RecID = ai.AGR_Header_RecID
                GROUP BY ah.AGR_Header_RecID
                ,ai.Month_Nbr
                ,ai.Year_Nbr) AS ar
            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT ah.AGR_Header_RecID
                ,DATEPART(MONTH, te.Date_Start) AS month
                ,DATEPART(YEAR, te.Date_Start) AS year
                ,SUM(te.AgrHrsCovered) AS hours
                ,CAST(SUM(te.AgrHrsCovered * te.Hourly_Cost_Decimal) AS NUMERIC (18, 2)) AS cost
                FROM v_rpt_time AS te
                INNER JOIN agr_header AS ah ON te.Agr_Header_RecID = ah.AGR_Header_RecID
                WHERE te.date_start >= DATEADD(mm, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                AND te.Agr_Header_RecID IS NOT NULL
                AND te.AgrHrsCovered IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY ah.AGR_Header_RecID
                ,DATEPART(MONTH, te.Date_Start)
                ,DATEPART(YEAR, te.Date_Start)) AS ac ON ar.AGR_Header_RecID = ac.AGR_Header_RecID
                     AND ar.Month = ac.Month
                     AND ar.Year = ac.Year
                LEFT JOIN
                    (SELECT SUM(vadi.Extended_Cost_Amount) AS prod_cost
                    ,vadi.AGR_Header_RecID
                    ,vadi.agr_month AS month
                    ,vadi.agr_year AS year
                    FROM iv_product vadi
                    GROUP BY vadi.AGR_Header_RecID
                    ,vadi.agr_month
                    ,vadi.agr_year) AS addi ON addi.AGR_Header_RecID = ar.AGR_Header_RecID AND ar.year = addi.year
                                                AND ar.month = addi.month
    ) AS ap ON ap.AGR_Header_RecID = al.AGR_Header_RecID
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ar.parent_recid
    ,ar.Month
    ,ar.Year
    ,ar.Rev
    ,ac.Hours AS hours
    ,ac.Cost AS labor_cost
    ,ar.child_agreeements
    ,ar.count
    ,ar.child_agreeement_types
    ,addi.prod_cost
    FROM
        (SELECT ah.parent_recid
        ,ai.Month_Nbr AS month
        ,ai.Year_Nbr AS year
        ,CAST(SUM(ai.Monthly_Inv_Amt - ai.Monthly_SalesTax_Amt) AS NUMERIC (18, 2)) AS rev
        ,SUBSTRING(
              (SELECT ', '+ahc.AGR_Name  AS [text()]
              FROM agr_header ahc
              WHERE ahc.parent_recid = ah.parent_Recid
              ORDER BY ahc.AGR_Name
              For XML PATH (''))
            , 2, 1000) [child_agreeements]
        ,SUBSTRING(
              (SELECT ', '+atc.AGR_Type_Desc  AS [text()]
              FROM agr_header ahc2
              INNER JOIN AGR_Type atc ON atc.AGR_Type_RecID = ahc2.AGR_Type_RecID
              WHERE ahc2.parent_recid = ah.parent_Recid
              ORDER BY atc.AGR_Type_Desc
              For XML PATH (''))
            , 2, 1000) [child_agreeement_types]
        ,COUNT(1) AS count
        FROM agr_header AS ah
        INNER JOIN agr_invoice_amt AS ai ON ah.AGR_Header_RecID = ai.AGR_Header_RecID
        GROUP BY ah.parent_Recid
        ,ai.Month_Nbr
        ,ai.Year_Nbr) AS ar
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT ah.parent_Recid
            ,DATEPART(MONTH, te.Date_Start) AS month
            ,DATEPART(YEAR, te.Date_Start) AS year
            ,SUM(te.AgrHrsCovered) AS hours
            ,CAST(SUM(te.AgrHrsCovered * te.Hourly_Cost_Decimal) AS NUMERIC (18, 2)) AS cost
            FROM v_rpt_time AS te
            INNER JOIN agr_header AS ah ON te.Agr_Header_RecID = ah.AGR_Header_RecID
            WHERE te.date_start >= DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
            AND te.Agr_Header_RecID IS NOT NULL
            AND te.AgrHrsCovered IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY ah.parent_Recid
            ,DATEPART(MONTH, te.Date_Start)
            ,DATEPART(YEAR, te.Date_Start)) AS ac ON ar.parent_recid = ac.parent_recid AND ar.Month = ac.Month
                                                        AND ar.Year = ac.Year
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT SUM(vadi.Extended_Cost_Amount) AS prod_cost
            ,ahp.parent_Recid
            ,vadi.agr_month AS month
            ,vadi.agr_year AS year
            FROM agr_header ahp
            INNER JOIN iv_product vadi ON vadi.AGR_Header_RecID = ahp.AGR_Header_RecID
            GROUP BY ahp.parent_Recid
            ,vadi.agr_month
            ,vadi.agr_year) AS addi ON addi.parent_Recid = ar.parent_Recid AND ar.year = addi.year AND ar.month = addi.month
    ) AS child ON child.parent_recid = al.AGR_Header_RecID AND child.month = ap.month AND child.year = ap.year





WHERE ah.parent_Recid IS NULL 
  AND ap.agr_date_inv > DATEADD(YEAR, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  AND ap.agr_date_inv <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  AND o.Owner_Level_Name IN ('Australia', 'Alex', 'Adam')
  AND al.Agreement_Status = 'active'
  AND al.Company_Name = 'Client A'
```

But it's not working.

This is the outcome (not pasting all the columns here) and a picture could be useful due the formating, its attached in the end:

id  Company_Name    AGR_Name    agr_type_desc   Valid_flag  date_start  date_end    billing_cycle   Billing_Amount  Agreement_Status    Sales Person
464-2-2022  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-2-2022  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex
464-6-2021  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-6-2021  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex
464-10-2020 Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-10-2020 Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex
464-4-2021  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-4-2021  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex
464-8-2020  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-8-2020  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex
464-11-2021 Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-11-2021 Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex
464-3-2021  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-3-2021  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex
464-7-2020  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-7-2020  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex
464-4-2022  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-4-2022  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex
464-1-2021  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-1-2021  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex
464-8-2021  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Adam
464-8-2021  Client A    Client A - BaaS Service -  User     Master Services Agreement   1   1/06/2020   NULL    Monthly 150 Active  Alex

[query outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/konA9.png)

Comment: (1) Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`, please tag only one. (2) Please do not post image, post it as text instead. (3) Also include sample data and the expected result and the current query (complete query)

Comment: I'm sorry for making so many mistakes. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Basically, I have used the function ROW_NUMBER, as shown in the line before your "id" column.
2. In case you do not want to show the "row number column" or "rn" in the results, you can replace the `*` in the following query, `SELECT * FROM TMP WHERE rnk = 1` to every column name you have previously mentioned except "rn".
3. Let me know if this works for you.

```
WITH TMP AS (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(al.agr_header_recid, '-', ap.month, '-', ap.year) ORDER BY o.Owner_Level_Name) as rn,
    CONCAT(al.agr_header_recid, '-', ap.month, '-', ap.year) AS id,
    al.Company_Name,
    ah.AGR_Name,
    al.agr_type_desc,
    al.Valid_flag,
    CAST(al.DateStart AS DATE) AS date_start,
    CAST(al.DateEND AS DATE) AS date_end,
    al.Billing_Cycle_Desc AS billing_cycle,
    al.Billing_Amount,
    al.Agreement_Status,
    o.Owner_Level_Name AS 'Sales Person',

    
    CASE
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'False' THEN 'Time'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'False' THEN 'Time & Expenses'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'True' THEN 'Time, Products, & Expenses'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'True' THEN 'Time & Products'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'False' THEN 'Expenses'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'True'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'True' THEN 'Products & Expenses'
    WHEN ah.PP_Time_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Expenses_Flag = 'False'
        AND ah.PP_Products_Flag = 'True' THEN 'Products'
    ELSE NULL
END AS agreement_covers_list
,CASE ah.AGR_NoEnd_Flag
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
END AS no_end_flag


,COALESCE(ap.Rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0) AS total_revenue
,CAST(ap.Agr_Date_inv AS DATE) AS date_agreement_invoiced
,COALESCE(ap.Hours, 0) + COALESCE(child.hours, 0) AS total_agreement_hours
,COALESCE(ap.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.labor_Cost, 0) AS total_labor_cost
,COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0) AS total_addition_cost
,CAST(CASE WHEN child.parent_recid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS has_child_agreement
,child.child_agreeements
,child.child_agreeement_types
,child.count AS number_of_child_agreements
,child.rev AS child_revenue
,ap.Rev AS parent_revenue
,ap.Hours AS parent_hours
,child.hours AS child_Hours
,ap.labor_Cost AS parent_labor_cost
,child.labor_Cost AS child_labor_cost
,ap.prod_cost AS parent_addition_cost
,child.prod_cost AS child_addition_cost
,COALESCE(ap.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0)
    + COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0) AS total_cost
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(ap.hours, 0) + COALESCE(child.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE (COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0))/(COALESCE(ap.hours, 0) + COALESCE(child.hours, 0))
END AS total_all_ehr
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(ap.hours, 0) + COALESCE(child.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE ((COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0)) - (COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0)))
           /(COALESCE(ap.hours, 0) + COALESCE(child.hours, 0))
END AS total_no_addition_cost_ehr
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(ap.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE (COALESCE(ap.rev, 0))/(COALESCE(ap.hours, 0))
END AS parent_all_ehr
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(ap.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE (COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) - COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0))/(COALESCE(ap.hours, 0))
END AS parent_no_addition_cost_ehr
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(child.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE (COALESCE(child.rev, 0) - COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0))/(COALESCE(child.hours, 0))
END AS child_no_addition_cost_ehr
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(child.hours, 0)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE (COALESCE(child.rev, 0))/(COALESCE(child.hours, 0))
END AS child_all_ehr
,(COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0))
    - (COALESCE(ap.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0))
AS total_agreement_margin
,CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0)) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ((COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0))
            - (COALESCE(ap.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(child.labor_Cost, 0) + COALESCE(ap.prod_cost, 0)
                + COALESCE(child.prod_cost, 0)))
        / ((COALESCE(ap.rev, 0) + COALESCE(child.rev, 0)))
END AS total_agreement_margin_percentage


FROM AGR_Header AS ah

INNER JOIN v_rpt_AgreementList AS al ON ah.AGR_Header_RecID = al.AGR_Header_RecID
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                    Company_RecID,
                    territory_recid

            FROM Billing_Log

            GROUP BY Company_RecID, territory_recid) AS bl ON ah.Company_RecID = bl.Company_RecID

INNER JOIN Owner_Level AS o ON bl.territory_recid = o.Owner_Level_RecID
INNER JOIN (SELECT ar.AGR_Header_RecID
            ,ar.Month
            ,ar.Year
            ,ar.Agr_Date_inv
            ,ar.Rev
            ,ac.Hours AS hours
            ,ac.Cost AS labor_cost
            ,addi.prod_cost
            FROM
                (SELECT ah.AGR_Header_RecID
                ,ai.Month_Nbr AS month
                ,ai.Year_Nbr AS year
                ,CONVERT (VARCHAR(8), ai.Year_Nbr, 120) + '-' + RIGHT ('0' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(8), ai.Month_nbr, 120), 2)
                    + '-' + '01' AS agr_date_inv
                ,CAST(SUM(ai.Monthly_Inv_Amt - ai.Monthly_SalesTax_Amt) AS NUMERIC (18, 2)) AS rev
                FROM agr_header AS ah
                INNER JOIN agr_invoice_amt AS ai ON ah.AGR_Header_RecID = ai.AGR_Header_RecID
                GROUP BY ah.AGR_Header_RecID
                ,ai.Month_Nbr
                ,ai.Year_Nbr) AS ar
            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT ah.AGR_Header_RecID
                ,DATEPART(MONTH, te.Date_Start) AS month
                ,DATEPART(YEAR, te.Date_Start) AS year
                ,SUM(te.AgrHrsCovered) AS hours
                ,CAST(SUM(te.AgrHrsCovered * te.Hourly_Cost_Decimal) AS NUMERIC (18, 2)) AS cost
                FROM v_rpt_time AS te
                INNER JOIN agr_header AS ah ON te.Agr_Header_RecID = ah.AGR_Header_RecID
                WHERE te.date_start >= DATEADD(mm, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                AND te.Agr_Header_RecID IS NOT NULL
                AND te.AgrHrsCovered IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY ah.AGR_Header_RecID
                ,DATEPART(MONTH, te.Date_Start)
                ,DATEPART(YEAR, te.Date_Start)) AS ac ON ar.AGR_Header_RecID = ac.AGR_Header_RecID
                     AND ar.Month = ac.Month
                     AND ar.Year = ac.Year
                LEFT JOIN
                    (SELECT SUM(vadi.Extended_Cost_Amount) AS prod_cost
                    ,vadi.AGR_Header_RecID
                    ,vadi.agr_month AS month
                    ,vadi.agr_year AS year
                    FROM iv_product vadi
                    GROUP BY vadi.AGR_Header_RecID
                    ,vadi.agr_month
                    ,vadi.agr_year) AS addi ON addi.AGR_Header_RecID = ar.AGR_Header_RecID AND ar.year = addi.year
                                                AND ar.month = addi.month
    ) AS ap ON ap.AGR_Header_RecID = al.AGR_Header_RecID
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ar.parent_recid
    ,ar.Month
    ,ar.Year
    ,ar.Rev
    ,ac.Hours AS hours
    ,ac.Cost AS labor_cost
    ,ar.child_agreeements
    ,ar.count
    ,ar.child_agreeement_types
    ,addi.prod_cost
    FROM
        (SELECT ah.parent_recid
        ,ai.Month_Nbr AS month
        ,ai.Year_Nbr AS year
        ,CAST(SUM(ai.Monthly_Inv_Amt - ai.Monthly_SalesTax_Amt) AS NUMERIC (18, 2)) AS rev
        ,SUBSTRING(
              (SELECT ', '+ahc.AGR_Name  AS [text()]
              FROM agr_header ahc
              WHERE ahc.parent_recid = ah.parent_Recid
              ORDER BY ahc.AGR_Name
              For XML PATH (''))
            , 2, 1000) [child_agreeements]
        ,SUBSTRING(
              (SELECT ', '+atc.AGR_Type_Desc  AS [text()]
              FROM agr_header ahc2
              INNER JOIN AGR_Type atc ON atc.AGR_Type_RecID = ahc2.AGR_Type_RecID
              WHERE ahc2.parent_recid = ah.parent_Recid
              ORDER BY atc.AGR_Type_Desc
              For XML PATH (''))
            , 2, 1000) [child_agreeement_types]
        ,COUNT(1) AS count
        FROM agr_header AS ah
        INNER JOIN agr_invoice_amt AS ai ON ah.AGR_Header_RecID = ai.AGR_Header_RecID
        GROUP BY ah.parent_Recid
        ,ai.Month_Nbr
        ,ai.Year_Nbr) AS ar
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT ah.parent_Recid
            ,DATEPART(MONTH, te.Date_Start) AS month
            ,DATEPART(YEAR, te.Date_Start) AS year
            ,SUM(te.AgrHrsCovered) AS hours
            ,CAST(SUM(te.AgrHrsCovered * te.Hourly_Cost_Decimal) AS NUMERIC (18, 2)) AS cost
            FROM v_rpt_time AS te
            INNER JOIN agr_header AS ah ON te.Agr_Header_RecID = ah.AGR_Header_RecID
            WHERE te.date_start >= DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
            AND te.Agr_Header_RecID IS NOT NULL
            AND te.AgrHrsCovered IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY ah.parent_Recid
            ,DATEPART(MONTH, te.Date_Start)
            ,DATEPART(YEAR, te.Date_Start)) AS ac ON ar.parent_recid = ac.parent_recid AND ar.Month = ac.Month
                                                        AND ar.Year = ac.Year
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT SUM(vadi.Extended_Cost_Amount) AS prod_cost
            ,ahp.parent_Recid
            ,vadi.agr_month AS month
            ,vadi.agr_year AS year
            FROM agr_header ahp
            INNER JOIN iv_product vadi ON vadi.AGR_Header_RecID = ahp.AGR_Header_RecID
            GROUP BY ahp.parent_Recid
            ,vadi.agr_month
            ,vadi.agr_year) AS addi ON addi.parent_Recid = ar.parent_Recid AND ar.year = addi.year AND ar.month = addi.month
    ) AS child ON child.parent_recid = al.AGR_Header_RecID AND child.month = ap.month AND child.year = ap.year





WHERE ah.parent_Recid IS NULL 
  AND ap.agr_date_inv > DATEADD(YEAR, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  AND ap.agr_date_inv <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  AND o.Owner_Level_Name IN ('Australia', 'Alex', 'Adam')
  AND al.Agreement_Status = 'active'
  AND al.Company_Name = 'Client A'
)


SELECT *
FROM TMP
WHERE rn = 1
```